Changing Rotate/Pan modes on the fly. Keymap settings
Worked a long time ago in NX Unigraphhics, and still have some habits from that CAD like switching Rotate/Pan modes on the fly(without releasing middle mouse).
I made this keymap settings.

And it works ok, but not quite right in this scenario of actions
Middle mouse - "moving mouse/check rotating" - pressing SHIFT(not releasing) - "moving mouse/check panning" - release middle mouse(for confirm) - "moving mouse/its still panning" - release SHIFT - "moving mouse/its still rotating".
The main thing is that it starts to rotate and pan without middle mouse pressed.
I just want to know is this a problem, or unknown for me commands are conflicting.
I tried to make additional commands like "CONFIRM - MIDDLE MOUSE - NOTHING" for both modes, hoping that blender will check status for MIDDLE MOUSE as unpressed. But it doesn't work.

